# How do I fix this Gradle Build Error while building my flutter app

Tags: flutter, gradle, java-8

I am trying to build my flutter apk with the command

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

But I get the following error:

```
 Building with sound null safety 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider_android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31.
 Required by:
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools:repository:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.3.1 > com.android.tools:common:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.3.1
  > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.31/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.31/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31.pom'.
           > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.67.
 Required by:
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.3.1
  > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.67.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.67/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.67.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.67/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.67.pom'.
           > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.17.2.
 Required by:
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.3.1-8691043
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-gradle-proto:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.3.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.3.1
      > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.17.2.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.17.2/protobuf-java-3.17.2.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.17.2/protobuf-java-3.17.2.pom'.
           > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.17.2.
 Required by:
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1
  > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.17.2.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.17.2/protobuf-java-util-3.17.2.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.17.2/protobuf-java-util-3.17.2.pom'.
           > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:1.39.0.
 Required by:
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.3.1
  > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:1.39.0.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.39.0/grpc-core-1.39.0.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.39.0/grpc-core-1.39.0.pom'.
           > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.39.0.
 Required by:
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.3.1
  > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.39.0.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.39.0/grpc-netty-1.39.0.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.39.0/grpc-netty-1.39.0.pom'.
           > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.39.0.
 Required by:
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.3.1
  > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.39.0.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-protobuf/1.39.0/grpc-protobuf-1.39.0.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-protobuf/1.39.0/grpc-protobuf-1.39.0.pom'.
           > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.39.0.
 Required by:
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.3.1
  > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.39.0.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-stub/1.39.0/grpc-stub-1.39.0.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-stub/1.39.0/grpc-stub-1.39.0.pom'.
           > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.67.
 Required by:
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.3.1
  > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.67.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.67/bcprov-jdk15on-1.67.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.67/bcprov-jdk15on-1.67.pom'.
           > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.31.
 Required by:
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.3.1
  > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.31.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.5.31/kotlin-reflect-1.5.31.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.5.31/kotlin-reflect-1.5.31.pom'.
           > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13.
 Required by:
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.3.1
     project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.3.1
  > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.13/httpcore-4.4.13.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.13/httpcore-4.4.13.pom'.
           > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

> Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13.
> Required by:
> project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.3.1
> > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.pom'.
> > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> Could not resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2.
> Required by:
> project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.3.1
> > Could not resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.pom'.
> > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13.
> Required by:
> project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6
> > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.pom'.
> > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.17.2.
> Required by:
> project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.9.0
> project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2
> > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.17.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.17.2/protobuf-java-3.17.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.17.2/protobuf-java-3.17.2.pom'.
> > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.17.2.
> Required by:
> project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.9.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.17.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.17.2/protobuf-java-util-3.17.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.17.2/protobuf-java-util-3.17.2.pom'.
> > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.71.
> Required by:
> project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta10
> project :path_provider_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta10
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.71.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.71/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.71.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.71/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.71.pom'.
> > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/192.168.1.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

```
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 59s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           61.1s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
```

NOTE: When I last time built another app, it built correctly but with a warning about something jdk version mismatch i dont remember exactly...

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: try `cd android` from root directory then `/.gradlew clean` followed by `./gradlew build`

Comment: @Harsh do you have internet access? or in another way do you have access to maven central or Jcentre repo?